# How do I add / pull data from a cell into a formula, using a variable?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, excel-formula, range

I named the range G4:G25 as **Range1** and I named range H4:H25 as **Range2**.

My code to pull data from Cell(2, 10) and then put it in the COVAR formula.

```vb
Sub abcd()
    Dim qwert As String
    qwert = Cells(2, 10).Address
    Range("G31").Formula = "=COVAR(" & qwert & ",H4:H25)"
    Range("G31").Select    
End Sub
```

The Cell(2, 10) has the value **Range1**, according to this, it should take the Range G4:G25 in the formula as I had defined the range in that way.

This is not giving me any output.

Comment: `Range("G31").Formula = "=COVAR(" & Cells(2, 10).Value  & ",Range2)"`. There is no need for the `quert` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
qwert = Cells(2, 10).Address
```

with:

```
qwert = Cells(2, 10).Value
```

Your posted code will then create this formula:

```
=COVAR(Range1,H4:H25)
```